# Map Route Direction Zoom to Segment

Tags: javascript, dictionary, esri, segment, arcgis-js-api

Basically I am trying to zoom to certain route segment when getting direction on OneMap. Here is the JavaScript codes where I trying to plot a route and zoom to certain route segment:

```
function getDirections() {
var routeData = new Route;
var from = document.getElementById('txtFrom').value
var to = document.getElementById('txtTo').value
//Draw out the line from the cordinate to another cordinate
routeData.routeStops = from + ";" + to;

//What type of mode will it do
routeData.routeMode = "DRIVE";
//can draw out untill the following coordiante
routeData.barriers = '36908.388637,35897.420831';
{
    if (document.getElementById('CbAvoid').checked) {
        routeData.avoidERP = "1";
    }
    else
        routeData.avoidERP = "0";
}
routeData.GetRoute(showRouteData)
}

function showRouteData(routeResults) {
    if (routeResults.results == "No results") {
        alert("No Route found, please try other location.")
        return
    }
    $('#divComputedDirection').show();
    directions = routeResults.results.directions[0];
    directionFeatures = directions.features;
    var routeSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([0, 0, 255, 0.5])).setWidth(4);
    var mergedGeometry = new esri.geometry.Polyline()

    mergedGeometry.addPath(routeResults.results.routes.features[0].geometry.paths[0])
    OneMap.map.graphics.add(new esri.Graphic(mergedGeometry, routeSymbol));
    //Display the total time and distance of the route                   
    var htmlStr = "";
    htmlStr += "<img class='close-image' onclick='closeDirectionResultDIV();' alt='close' src='img/closeDirectionResult.png' />";
    htmlStr += "<span style='font-weight:bold;'><br /> &nbsp; Total distance: " + Math.round(directions.summary.totalLength) + "km" + "<br /> &nbsp; Total time: " + Math.round(directions.summary.totalTime) + "mins <br/></span>";

    document.getElementById("divComputedDirection").innerHTML = htmlStr;

    //List the directions and create hyperlinks for each route segment
    for (var i = 0; i < directions.features.length; i++) {
        var feature = directions.features[i]
        document.getElementById("divComputedDirection").innerHTML += '<a href="JavaScript:zoomToSegment(' + i + ')" style="font-size: 11px"><br>' + parseInt(parseInt(i) + 1) + ". " + feature.attributes.text + " (" + formatDistance(feature.attributes.length, "miles") + ", " + formatTime(feature.attributes.time) + ") " + '</a>';
    }
}

//Zoom to the appropriate segment when the user clicks a hyperlink in the directions list
function zoomToSegment(index) {
var segment = directionFeatures[index];
map.setExtent(segment.geometry.getExtent(), true);
if (!segmentGraphic) {
    segmentGraphic = map.graphics.add(new esri.Graphic(segment.geometry, segmentSymbol));
}
else {
    segmentGraphic.setGeometry(segment.geometry);
}
```

}

It did plot the route and show all the directions. But when I click on certain direction and zoom to segement, it throws me an error message which is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getExtent' of undefined`.

I wonder why is it so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any clues to solve this?

Comment: Where do you define `directionFeatures`? If you're not defining it outside the `showRouteData()` function, then it's a local variable to that function - when the event handler triggers `zoomToSegment` then `directionFeatures` no longer exists.

Comment: @Juffy I defined it as a global variable. Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: Not without seeing a working example, no - I would fire up a debugger (eg. Chrome's F12 dev tools) and have a look at what's in your `directionFeatures` array when the `zoomToSegment` function executes.

Comment: @Juffy It return me an Object with the attributes of ETA: -2209161600000 length: 0.1689308050723526 maneuverType: "esriDMTTurnRight" text: "Turn right at TIONG POH ROAD to stay on TIONG BAHRU ROAD" time: 0.25339999999999996. What does the getExtent() do actually? and segment.geometry returns me an undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your error is that you're trying to get the extent of a `.geometry` property that doesn't exist - that part is relatively easy. The problem, I think, is that you're looking for the geometry of each segment of the journey, and the return from OneMap's [RouteTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_route_routetask.html) doesn't give you that directly.

The geometry from the entire route is in

```
routeResults.results.routes.features[0].geometry.paths[0]
```

and the individual segments are in one of ESRI's fun compressed formats in the value:

```
routeResults.results.directions[x].features[y].compressedGeometry
```

There's some documentation and C# code for this compressed format here:

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/ArcObjects/esrinetworkanalyst/INACompactStreetDirection_CompressedGeometry.htm

It should be relatively easy to port that C# code to JS if you really need the geometry of individual segments.

OneMap have a full working example [here](http://www.onemap.sg/api/help/HTMLSource/Routing.aspx) which shows how to process the results from the RouteTask, but unfortunately they don't attempt to extract the compressedGeometry field.

---

**Edit:** More sample code from ESRI [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/java/details?entryID=7B5F4B9F-1422-2418-A0AA-E4F68C404124), with examples in C#/Java/Python.

Comment: As in the code to solve this problem. Because from the documentation you provided, I have no idea how to extract the compressedGeometry field.

Comment: I'll have a crack at porting that C# code when I get a chance, and update my answer.

Comment: Basically I just convert all the code in Program.cs from the link you provided into JavaScript. Then, I will pass the segment into CreatePathFromCompressedGeometry(). Am I nearly there or?

Comment: That's the idea - that should give you a `Path` you can add to a `Polyline` and away you go.

Comment: But do you have any idea to convert C# code into JavaScript? Because when I tried to convert, there's some error.

Comment: Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Port of C# code into typescript: https://gist.github.com/ca0v/6a09c2fe6dfdfc0f5192